Why doesn't Graphics.Clear appear to work properly in my custom Windows forms control?
My understanding of how you should draw a custom Windows forms control is to first call Graphics.Clear to refresh the control's background, then draw whatever you want on top of that.  As such, I have the following code for the custom control I'm developing:
internal class PictureSizeCropBox : Control {
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs ea) {
        ea.Graphics.Clear(Color.Green);

        Pen redPen = new(Color.Red, 1);

        ea.Graphics.DrawRectangle(redPen, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1));
    }
}

However, when I put that in a Panel and my code resizes the control (and panel) upon window resize, I get this graphical effect when the window is made larger:

What is Graphics.Clear doing?  It is drawing a green background initially but weirdly, it's not actually clearing the old stuff rendered by the control.  What is the correct way to draw Windows forms controls so they correctly redraw upon resize, clearing the old rendering?  Do I need to just draw a filled rectangle for the background and if so, what is the point in Graphics.Clear and when should it be used?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.resizeredraw?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Apparently, you need to explicitly invalidate your control on resize:
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs ea) {
        base.OnResize(ea);
        Invalidate();
    }

Adding this fixes the problem.

In the Constructor of your Custom Control, add SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true) (OptimizedDoubleBuffer because the Control has Picture in its name, so this may become useful). You can remove the OnResize override -- If the Pen is static (the Color doesn't change, use a stock object: Pens.Red, otherwise, declare the Pen with a using statement) -- Graphics.Clear() is not that useful if it relates to the entire Control; set the BackColor instead, otherwise you end up painting the whole surface twice

Ah, didn't realize that setting BackColor just drew the background anyway!
